# Cracking MD4 hash

Tags: hash, password-cracking

I'm doing some hacking exercices and I have to gain access to a site's database so I can delete all records.

The way of getting into the administrator panel is through a password (no username). I've tried some ways of getting in (SQLi, SSI, cookies) but didn't succeed. But, reading through some of the site's pages, I found something on the "news" talking about Google crawling some links it shouldn't and that they fixed it, so checking the **robots.txt** file gives me a **/secret** directory in which there is a php file called **admin.php** (the one that checks for correct password) and **admin.bak.php**. When opened the backup one, it returned:

> error matching hash dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016

That hash is MD4 as I found a file on one of the server's hidden directories where they were trying to generate a MD4 hash.

I've tried:

```
findmyhash -h dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016
```

and

```
hashcat -m 900 -a 0 dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016
```

but none of them were able to crack it. How could I do this?

Comment: @sysfired I'd simply call it *MD4-hashing*. For one, *encrypting* suggests that it's reversible which hashing is not.

Comment: "how you could do this" is too broad to answer - 'cracking' hashes requires a wordlist to compare against: you will need that wordlist.

Comment: @sysfiend still confused: both commands appear to be improperly formed

Comment: Alright, so I was just aproaching it the wrong way. You are right @schroeder I would need a word list but you can actually gain access to the admin panel just by finding a collision, which is way easier and faster. I'll answer asap to clarify. Thanks for help

Comment: @sysfiend How would finding a collision help you?

Comment: @CodesInChaos they take they password, hash it and then compare it to the hashed one they have storage, finding a collision gives me a word, which is nor the password, but generates a hash that validates me and lets me in.

Comment: @sysfiend A collision attack requires the attacker to control both messages and thus is pointless for password hashes. Finding a message given only the hash is called a first preimage attack and should still be infeasible, despite MD4 being horribly broken, so I don't see a way around guessing the original password.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the thing is, I don't need the password, just to get into the admin panel, which I did by using a word that creates the same hash as the correct password

Comment: @sysfiend But how would you find another password matching a given MD4 hash? As far as I know, there is no known attack against MD4 which allows you to find a first preimage.

Comment: isn't the word that creates the same hash as the correct password, the password ? :)

Comment: you could write your own script to crack the md4 hash, using python 2 would be the best : https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html

Answer (score 4):

> How can I crack this hash?

John and Hashcat will both do this, but try not to be dependent on one password-cracking program.

## Hashcat (Windows Example)

With hashcat, you will either need a wordlist and/or rule that contains/generates the password, or you'll need to start from nothing with no wordlist (brute force). This may take a while depending on many factors (hardware, algorithms, etc).

Your hashcat format is *almost* correct. You'll want to brute-force it with the '`-a 3`' switch:

`hashcat32.exe -m 900 dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016 -a 3 -o cracked.txt`

> dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016:**3b452**

Try the `--help` switch or, if you want to view more attack modes:

`hashcat32.exe --help | findstr "\-a"`:

> Wordlist: `hashcat -a 0 -m 400 example400.hash example.dict`
>
> Wordlist + Rules: `hashcat -a 0 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict -r rules/best64.rule`
>
> **Brute-Force**: `hashcat -a 3 -m 0 example0.hash ?a?a?a?a?a?a`
>
> Combinator `hashcat -a 1 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict example.dict`

---

## John The Ripper (Linux Example)

John's requirements are the same as above, but with different command switches. John also finds this quickly without need for a wordlist:

`echo dc2240d8ee745db929a6944ae7a8d016 > test.md4 && john test.md4 --format=Raw-MD4 --show`

> ?:3b452
>
> 1 password hash cracked, 0 left

---

Password is **3b452**.

Answer (score 3):

Found something with john the ripper within 1 min,

try  `john --show --format=Raw-MD4 File-Containing-The-Hash`